# angular js v-1.2.20 issue with angular-slider

Tags: angularjs, version

I am trying to implement [angular-slider](http://plnkr.co/edit/hNg2gOTHa7ig2hPsrmZ8?p=preview) using angularJS v-1.2.20.

```
<div ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
  <slider custom-floor="item.minAge" floor="100" custom-ceiling="item.maxAge" ceiling="1000" step="10" precision="2" ng-model="item.cost"></slider>
</div>
```

After including all necessary js and css files, the slider is shown but the floor and ceiling values(and also custom floor and custom ceiling values) are not getting displayed.

There is no error in console. But when I used angular v-1.1.4 in the script without changing any code, everything seems to work fine.

Does anybody know about this issue. Any workaround if I need to use slider with angular v-1.2.20.?

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all sorry for my english,the ng-bind-html-unsafe was deleted of angular js so we now need to use directly "{{}}"  in html code i just change attribute by a call in html and angular slider works with at least angular  1.2.9 that i used, here a complete exemple.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="APP">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>angular-slider example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.directiv.es/application/html/js/prajwalkman/angular-slider/angular-slider.min.css" media="all">
</head>
<body>

<div style="width:600px;" ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
  <slider floor="0" ceiling="100" step="1" precision="2" ng-model="cost"></slider>
</div>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.2
(function() {
var MODULE_NAME, SLIDER_TAG, angularize, bindHtml, gap, halfWidth, hide, inputEvents, module, offset, offsetLeft, pixelize, qualifiedDirectiveDefinition, roundStep, show, sliderDirective, width;
MODULE_NAME = 'uiSlider';
SLIDER_TAG = 'slider';
angularize = function(element) {
return angular.element(element);
};
pixelize = function(position) {
return "" + position + "px";
};
hide = function(element) {
return element.css({
opacity: 0
});
};
show = function(element) {
return element.css({
opacity: 1
});
};
offset = function(element, position) {
return element.css({
left: position
});
};
halfWidth = function(element) {
return element[0].offsetWidth / 2;
};
offsetLeft = function(element) {
return element[0].offsetLeft;
};
width = function(element) {
return element[0].offsetWidth;
};
gap = function(element1, element2) {
return offsetLeft(element2) - offsetLeft(element1) - width(element1);
};
bindHtml = function(element, html) {

};
roundStep = function(value, precision, step, floor) {
var decimals, remainder, roundedValue, steppedValue;
if (floor == null) {
floor = 0;
}
if (step == null) {
step = 1 / Math.pow(10, precision);
}
remainder = (value - floor) % step;
steppedValue = remainder > (step / 2) ? value + step - remainder : value - remainder;
decimals = Math.pow(10, precision);
roundedValue = steppedValue * decimals / decimals;
return roundedValue.toFixed(precision);
};
inputEvents = {
mouse: {
start: 'mousedown',
move: 'mousemove',
end: 'mouseup'
},
touch: {
start: 'touchstart',
move: 'touchmove',
end: 'touchend'
}
};
sliderDirective = function($timeout) {
return {
restrict: 'EA',
scope: {
floor: '@',
ceiling: '@',
step: '@',
precision: '@',
ngModel: '=?',
ngModelLow: '=?',
ngModelHigh: '=?',
translate: '&'
},
template: '<span class="bar"></span><span class="bar selection"></span><span class="pointer"></span><span class="pointer"></span><span class="bubble selection"></span><span class="bubble limit"> {{floor}}</span><span class="bubble limit">{{ ceiling}}</span><span class="bubble">{{ngModel}}</span><span class="bubble"></span><span class="bubble"></span>',
compile: function(element, attributes) {
var ceilBub, cmbBub, e, flrBub, fullBar, highBub, lowBub, maxPtr, minPtr, range, refHigh, refLow, selBar, selBub, watchables, _i, _len, _ref, _ref1;
if (attributes.translate) {
attributes.$set('translate', "" + attributes.translate + "(value)");
}
range = (attributes.ngModel == null) && ((attributes.ngModelLow != null) && (attributes.ngModelHigh != null));
_ref = (function() {
var _i, _len, _ref, _results;
_ref = element.children();
_results = [];
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
e = _ref[_i];
_results.push(angularize(e));
}
return _results;
})(), fullBar = _ref[0], selBar = _ref[1], minPtr = _ref[2], maxPtr = _ref[3], selBub = _ref[4], flrBub = _ref[5], ceilBub = _ref[6], lowBub = _ref[7], highBub = _ref[8], cmbBub = _ref[9];
refLow = range ? 'ngModelLow' : 'ngModel';
refHigh = 'ngModelHigh';
bindHtml(selBub, "'Range: ' + translate({value: diff})");
bindHtml(lowBub, "translate({value: " + refLow + "})");
bindHtml(highBub, "translate({value: " + refHigh + "})");
bindHtml(cmbBub, "translate({value: " + refLow + "}) + ' - ' + translate({value: " + refHigh + "})");
if (!range) {
_ref1 = [selBar, maxPtr, selBub, highBub, cmbBub];
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref1.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
element = _ref1[_i];
element.remove();
}
}
watchables = [refLow, 'floor', 'ceiling'];
if (range) {
watchables.push(refHigh);
}
return {
post: function(scope, element, attributes) {
var barWidth, boundToInputs, dimensions, maxOffset, maxValue, minOffset, minValue, ngDocument, offsetRange, pointerHalfWidth, updateDOM, valueRange, w, _j, _len1;
boundToInputs = false;
ngDocument = angularize(document);
if (!attributes.translate) {
scope.translate = function(value) {
return value.value;
};
}
pointerHalfWidth = barWidth = minOffset = maxOffset = minValue = maxValue = valueRange = offsetRange = void 0;
dimensions = function() {
var value, _j, _len1, _ref2, _ref3;
if ((_ref2 = scope.precision) == null) {
scope.precision = 0;
}
if ((_ref3 = scope.step) == null) {
scope.step = 1;
}
for (_j = 0, _len1 = watchables.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
value = watchables[_j];
scope[value] = roundStep(parseFloat(scope[value]), parseInt(scope.precision), parseFloat(scope.step), parseFloat(scope.floor));
}
scope.diff = roundStep(scope[refHigh] - scope[refLow], parseInt(scope.precision), parseFloat(scope.step), parseFloat(scope.floor));
pointerHalfWidth = halfWidth(minPtr);
barWidth = width(fullBar);
minOffset = 0;
maxOffset = barWidth - width(minPtr);
minValue = parseFloat(attributes.floor);
maxValue = parseFloat(attributes.ceiling);
valueRange = maxValue - minValue;
return offsetRange = maxOffset - minOffset;
};
updateDOM = function() {
var adjustBubbles, bindToInputEvents, fitToBar, percentOffset, percentToOffset, percentValue, setBindings, setPointers;
dimensions();
percentOffset = function(offset) {
return ((offset - minOffset) / offsetRange) * 100;
};
percentValue = function(value) {
return ((value - minValue) / valueRange) * 100;
};
percentToOffset = function(percent) {
return pixelize(percent * offsetRange / 100);
};
fitToBar = function(element) {
return offset(element, pixelize(Math.min(Math.max(0, offsetLeft(element)), barWidth - width(element))));
};
setPointers = function() {
var newHighValue, newLowValue;
offset(ceilBub, pixelize(barWidth - width(ceilBub)));
newLowValue = percentValue(scope[refLow]);
offset(minPtr, percentToOffset(newLowValue));
offset(lowBub, pixelize(offsetLeft(minPtr) - (halfWidth(lowBub)) + pointerHalfWidth));
if (range) {
newHighValue = percentValue(scope[refHigh]);
offset(maxPtr, percentToOffset(newHighValue));
offset(highBub, pixelize(offsetLeft(maxPtr) - (halfWidth(highBub)) + pointerHalfWidth));
offset(selBar, pixelize(offsetLeft(minPtr) + pointerHalfWidth));
selBar.css({
width: percentToOffset(newHighValue - newLowValue)
});
offset(selBub, pixelize(offsetLeft(selBar) + halfWidth(selBar) - halfWidth(selBub)));
return offset(cmbBub, pixelize(offsetLeft(selBar) + halfWidth(selBar) - halfWidth(cmbBub)));
}
};
adjustBubbles = function() {
var bubToAdjust;
fitToBar(lowBub);
bubToAdjust = highBub;
if (range) {
fitToBar(highBub);
fitToBar(selBub);
if (gap(lowBub, highBub) < 10) {
hide(lowBub);
hide(highBub);
fitToBar(cmbBub);
show(cmbBub);
bubToAdjust = cmbBub;
} else {
show(lowBub);
show(highBub);
hide(cmbBub);
bubToAdjust = highBub;
}
}
if (gap(flrBub, lowBub) < 5) {
hide(flrBub);
} else {
if (range) {
if (gap(flrBub, bubToAdjust) < 5) {
hide(flrBub);
} else {
show(flrBub);
}
} else {
show(flrBub);
}
}
if (gap(lowBub, ceilBub) < 5) {
return hide(ceilBub);
} else {
if (range) {
if (gap(bubToAdjust, ceilBub) < 5) {
return hide(ceilBub);
} else {
return show(ceilBub);
}
} else {
return show(ceilBub);
}
}
};
bindToInputEvents = function(pointer, ref, events) {
var onEnd, onMove, onStart;
onEnd = function() {
pointer.removeClass('active');
ngDocument.unbind(events.move);
return ngDocument.unbind(events.end);
};
onMove = function(event) {
var eventX, newOffset, newPercent, newValue;
eventX = event.clientX || event.touches[0].clientX;
newOffset = eventX - element[0].getBoundingClientRect().left - pointerHalfWidth;
newOffset = Math.max(Math.min(newOffset, maxOffset), minOffset);
newPercent = percentOffset(newOffset);
newValue = minValue + (valueRange * newPercent / 100.0);
if (range) {
if (ref === refLow) {
if (newValue > scope[refHigh]) {
ref = refHigh;
minPtr.removeClass('active');
maxPtr.addClass('active');
}
} else {
if (newValue < scope[refLow]) {
ref = refLow;
maxPtr.removeClass('active');
minPtr.addClass('active');
}
}
}
newValue = roundStep(newValue, parseInt(scope.precision), parseFloat(scope.step), parseFloat(scope.floor));
scope[ref] = newValue;
return scope.$apply();
};
onStart = function(event) {
pointer.addClass('active');
dimensions();
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
ngDocument.bind(events.move, onMove);
return ngDocument.bind(events.end, onEnd);
};
return pointer.bind(events.start, onStart);
};
setBindings = function() {
var bind, inputMethod, _j, _len1, _ref2, _results;
boundToInputs = true;
bind = function(method) {
bindToInputEvents(minPtr, refLow, inputEvents[method]);
return bindToInputEvents(maxPtr, refHigh, inputEvents[method]);
};
_ref2 = ['touch', 'mouse'];
_results = [];
for (_j = 0, _len1 = _ref2.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
inputMethod = _ref2[_j];
_results.push(bind(inputMethod));
}
return _results;
};
setPointers();
adjustBubbles();
if (!boundToInputs) {
return setBindings();
}
};
$timeout(updateDOM);
for (_j = 0, _len1 = watchables.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
w = watchables[_j];
scope.$watch(w, updateDOM);
}
return window.addEventListener("resize", updateDOM);
}
};
}
};
};
qualifiedDirectiveDefinition = ['$timeout', sliderDirective];
module = function(window, angular) {
return angular.module(MODULE_NAME, []).directive(SLIDER_TAG, qualifiedDirectiveDefinition);
};
module(window, window.angular);
}).call(this);</script>
    <script>
    app = angular.module('APP', ['uiSlider']);
    app.controller('ItemCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.cost = 0
    }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```